# Concatenation in XML

Tags: java, android, xml

Is it possible to concatenate a string from my java code for one of the activities to a string in another xml file? More specifically I have just added a popup Window and I would like it to give a message 'Congrats! You have obtained A', where A is the string from my activity and should be able to get different values.
So basically my question is if there is a way to concatenate

```
 `public String letter;`
```

from my java file to

```
`android:text="@string/popup_text"`
```

from my xml file?

Comment: Just an FYI-  you can do this, but the result may not be grammatical or even make sense in a language other than english.  Not all languages have verb->noun ordering like that.  If your app is being internationalized, its better to put in the letter as a parameter so the translators can translate it knowing it will be filled in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must take reference to your TextView, then you can do something like this:

```
textView.setText(textView.getText().toString() + letter);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, just one more question though if I have more than one TextViews that would get concatenated to different strings how should I define the different textViews? By referencing their ids somehow? How would that happen?

Comment: I'm not sure to have understood your question, please explain me, I'll be happy to help you

Comment: If there is more than one textView on a screen and they contain different information(strings) and I would like to add two different values to them, how should I tell the program to which textView I want to concatenate which value? Did I manage to explain it this time? I could try to add some code if that can help clarity things

Comment: you need to inflate all your TextView in different variable. Search something like "android inflate view"

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the API for [string resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

In your case, consider either:

```
textView.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.popup_text) + " " + letter);
```

Or to format the string resource with `String.format` by having the string resource look like

```
<string name="popup_text"> Congrats! You have obtained %1$s!</string>
```

And then in your activity or fragment:

```
Resources res = getResources();
testView.setText(String.format(res.getString(R.string.popup_text), letter);
```